Regex: Find matches only outside of single quotes
I currently have a regex that selects all occurrences of (, , , );:
(\s\()|(,\s)|(\),)|(\);)
however, I've been trying to figure out a way so that if anything is between single quotes 'like this, for example', it'll ignore any of the matches listed above. I tried many different solutions, however none of them seemed to work for me.
Does anyone know of ways I could make this work?

Can you update your question with inputs and expected outputs?

To add to the above comment, what is your actual goal here and what are you trying to match/extract?

To add the obligatory, this is not a regular language, regexp can not parse it.

How would literal single quotes (that must be part of a text) be encoded in this input format?

Expressing a not-find is a tricky thing, as everything around a regex is designed to work in a positive / greedy way (find as much as possible, whenever somehow possible).
The easiest and most likely fastest thing you could to is to remove the parts you want to exclude prior to applying your search, assuming quotes always appear in pairs:
"'[^']*'" => ""

and then apply your search to the remaining string. If the string needs to be modified "inplace", you could first search for these things and replace them with arbitrary, non-colliding placeholders that do not appear naturally, and replace them later again. (I quite often use something like ###Placeholder1### or something for that purpose. Easy to match and replace again, and almost guaranteed to not appear elsewhere naturally).
Python example:
import re

text = "this is a , and this a ( whith a ) while 'this ( is in quotes,therefore excluded' unlike these: ( ) , but 'these () are again'. period."
print(text)
placeholders = []
def repl(m):
    contents = m.group(1)
    placeholders.append(contents)
    return "###Placeholder{0}###".format(len(placeholders) - 1)

temp=re.sub('(\'[^\']*\')', repl, text)
print(temp)

temp=re.sub('([,\)\(])', "`\\1`", temp)
print(temp)
for k in range(len(placeholders)):
  temp = re.sub("###Placeholder{0}###".format(k), placeholders[k], temp)

print(temp)

(Note that the ### also ensures that Placeholder1 and Placeholder13 won't collide later on.)

this is a , and this a ( whith a ) while 'this ( is in
quotes,therefore excluded' unlike these: ( ) , but 'these () are
again'. period.
this is a , and this a ( whith a ) while ###Placeholder0### unlike
these: ( ) , but ###Placeholder1###. period.
this is a , and this a ( whith a ) while ###Placeholder0###
unlike these: ( ) , but ###Placeholder1###. period.
this is a , and this a ( whith a ) while 'this ( is in
quotes,therefore excluded' unlike these: ( ) , but 'these () are
again'. period.


Or with the pythonic * operator, the final round of re-replacing could be omitted. (This however may cause issues if {0} and stuff appear naturally):
import re

text = "this is a , and this a ( whith a ) while 'this ( is in quotes,therefore excluded' unlike these: ( ) , but 'these () are again'. period."
print(text)
placeholders = []
def repl(m):
    placeholders.append(m.group(1))
    return "{"+"{0}".format(len(placeholders) - 1) + "}"

temp=re.sub('(\'[^\']+\')', repl, text)
print(temp)

temp=re.sub('([,\)\(])', "`\\1`", temp)
print(temp)

temp = temp.format(*placeholders)
print(temp)


You can use a pattern like ('[^']*')|(\s\()|(,\s)|(\),)|(\);) and filter those substrings that you don't want
import re

p = r"('[^']*')|(\s\()|(,\s)|(\),)|(\);)"
s = """'like this, for example' ("""
print([m for match in re.findall(p, s) for m in match if m and not match[0].startswith("'")])


Prints

[' (']


Note:

('[^']*') is the part that you want to exclude.


The problem with this is that you need to match the entire string from beginning to end to identify which single quotes are opening ones and which are closing ones. But try something like
re.findall(
    r"(?:(?:'[^']*')[^']*)*(\s\()|(,\s)|(\),)|(\);)",
    text)

which adds (?:(?:'[^']*')[^']*)* in front of your capturing expression.
This will work oddly for inputs with unpaired single quotes, but it should work fine if your inputs are simple and regular (and if not, you probably need something more powerful than just regular expressions anyway).
